# Querying over a range in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a SQLite table that has a ton of data in it, millions of rows. There's a row inserted about every second.

The rows have a column for the Created date, which is converted into milliseconds since Epoch and saved as a number, such as 1343224574667. Each row also has a column for the ID of a container, it's just a string field.

I'm trying to run a query to get items that were created within a certain time range for a certain container Id. So the query would look something like

```
Select * from Item where Created > [number] and Created < [number] and ContainerId=[string]
```

Pretty basic query.

I have a few indexes on the table. There's one on [Created], and there's one on [Created, ContainerId]. When I run this query on a small time range, the query is pretty fast, like a few hundred milliseconds. Expand it out however so that the time range extends over a week or so, and this query is brutally slow, over 75 seconds on average. Is there any way to speed this up? This seems like a crazy long time to have to wait for results. But I'm no DBA, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Greater range probably have a lot more distinct ContainerIds. What happens if you reverse column's order in index? `[ContainerID, Created]`?

Comment: It was still slow, but that may be just this particular case. Should I have indexes in both directions to cover both cases? Or is that too much...

Comment: I think it would be too much. Not sure how much Sqlite uses statistics to be able to choose among similar indexes. Especially as it seems that row lookup is the problem (many reads from Item table).

Comment: Maybe it also has something to do with the fact that the table is constantly having data written to it. Is there some kind of concept of querying `WITH (NOLOCK)` like in SQL Server?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Sqlite. [There is an article talking about isolation levels - see 2.2.1 Read-Uncommitted Isolation Mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html).

Answer (score 0):

A **clustered index** can speed up querying over a range. In case of SQLite that probably means using the primary key. If you can, try making (Created, ContainerId) the PRIMARY KEY of the table.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option. Each row has its own unique identifier.